# coredata vs sqlite

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use CoreData or SQLite on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318467/use-coredata-or-sqlite-on-iphone)

what is the difference between coredata and sqlite?

when we have to use coredata ?

when we have to use sqlite ?

Comment: Does't sound like a real question and the chance of closing this question is more. Wht not say what your situation is and ask whether xyz DB is better or abc is better?

Answer (score 0):

There's no "have to". If you are more comfortable with sqlite then by all means use it. However Core Data is very convenient for all kinds of reasons such as built-in schema editing in Xcode, object model class generation, faulting (load one object, follow your object graph all over your model...)

But don't take my word for it, see [this very well-answered Stack Overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523482/core-data-vs-sqlite-3)