# Local Database iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, plist

I have 15k entries and i want store them in local database. Further in iOS app I m going to use this data. For this which local database should I prefer in terms of performance also? How should I proceed? How much maximum data can I store locally?

Thanks in advance

Comment: data of 15k items/students/stores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Core Data for the same scenario like this. I have found the below tutorial very useful

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I m not aware of core data, I m little bit aware of sqllite so can i use sqllite in above scenario?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390605/best-way-to-store-data-on-iphone/6391408#6391408 Technically, Core Data is better for most cases, but if you are familiar with SQLite and not Core Data is your choice, both do the job.

Comment: You can use sqlite also for the above scenario. I used both sqlite and coredata and i found coredata more effective and easy

Answer (score 1):

Use core data with sqlite. I think you have 2GB of local disk space to play with.