# Deserializing local NSString of JSON into objects via RestKit (no network download)

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit

Is it possible to deserialize an `NSString` of JSON into objects via RestKit? I checked the API list [here](http://restkit.org/api/0.9/Classes/) and could not find something that would serve for this purpose. The closest I could find are the various parser classes that return `NSDictionary` after parsing the input. I assume RestKit uses these parsers after downloading the response so my thinking is that the functionality is available somewhere in RestKit but not exposed publicly.

If I am not missing anything and this functionality is not exposed, what would be the alternatives? Two obvious ones do not look very promising: Get the resulting `NSDictionary` and try to deserialize myself (effectively reimplementing RestKit) or try to dive into RestKit source and see if this can be somehow exposed (looks tedious and error prone).

Thanks in advance for any help.

PS: The idea is that a string property on a deserialized object is actually the JSON representation of another set of objects (embedded JSON in a sense) and it is deserialized on demand during runtime.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty "simple":

```
NSString *stringJSON;
...

RKJSONParserJSONKit *parser;
NSError *error= nil;
parser= [[[RKJSONParserJSONKit alloc] init] autorelease]; 
MyManagedObject *target;
target= [MyManagedObject object];

NSDictionary *objectAsDictionary;
RKObjectMapper* mapper;
objectAsDictionary= [parser objectFromString:stringJSON error:&error];
mapper = [RKObjectMapper mapperWithObject:objectAsDictionary 
                          mappingProvider:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider];
mapper.targetObject = target;
RKObjectMappingResult* result = [mapper performMapping];
NSLog(@"%@", [result asObject]);
```

Answer (score 8):

As of [RestKit 0.20.0-pre2](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping)

```
NSString* JSONString = @"{ \"name\": \"The name\", \"number\": 12345}";
NSString* MIMEType = @"application/json";
NSError* error;
NSData *data = [JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id parsedData = [RKMIMETypeSerialization objectFromData:data MIMEType:MIMEType error:&error];
if (parsedData == nil && error) {
    // Parser error...
}

AppUser *appUser = [[AppUser alloc] init];

NSDictionary *mappingsDictionary = @{ @"someKeyPath": someMapping };
RKMapperOperation *mapper = [[RKMapperOperation alloc] initWithRepresentation:parsedData mappingsDictionary:mappingsDictionary];
mapper.targetObject = appUser;
NSError *mappingError = nil;
BOOL isMapped = [mapper execute:&mappingError];
if (isMapped && !mappingError) {
    // Yay! Mapping finished successfully
    NSLog(@"mapper: %@", [mapper representation]);
    NSLog(@"firstname is %@", appUser.firstName);
}
```

Comment: Do you know perhaps how to do this from an already configured RKObjectManager?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#centralize-configuration-in-an-object-manager

Answer (score 5):

This works for Restkit 0.21.0:

```
NSString* jsonFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName"
                                                 ofType:@"json"];

NSString* JSONString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsonFilePath
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];


NSError* error;
NSData *data = [JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id parsedData = [RKMIMETypeSerialization objectFromData:data MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON error:&error];
if (parsedData == nil && error) {
    // Parser error...
}

//_objectManager is RKObjectManager instance
NSMutableDictionary *mappingsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (RKResponseDescriptor *descriptor in _objectManager.responseDescriptors) {
    [mappingsDictionary setObject:descriptor.mapping forKey:descriptor.keyPath];
}

RKMapperOperation *mapper = [[RKMapperOperation alloc] initWithRepresentation:parsedData mappingsDictionary:mappingsDictionary];
NSError *mappingError = nil;
BOOL isMapped = [mapper execute:&mappingError];
if (isMapped && !mappingError) {
    NSLog(@"result %@",[mapper mappingResult]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for Restkit 0.20, using **Core Data Entities**. It is based in the solution given by @innerself

```
NSString* jsonFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"info-base"
                                                         ofType:@"json"];

NSString* JSONString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsonFilePath
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                    error:NULL];


NSError *error = nil;

NSData *data = [JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id parsedData = [RKMIMETypeSerialization objectFromData:data MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON error:&error];
if (parsedData == nil && error) {
    // Parser error...
    NSLog(@"parse error");
}

//_objectManager is RKObjectManager instance
NSMutableDictionary *mappingsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (RKResponseDescriptor *descriptor in [RKObjectManager sharedManager].responseDescriptors) {

    [mappingsDictionary setObject:descriptor.mapping forKey:descriptor.keyPath];
}

RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource *datasource = [[RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource alloc]
                                                         initWithManagedObjectContext:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].persistentStoreManagedObjectContext
                                                                                cache:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].managedObjectCache];

RKMapperOperation *mapper = [[RKMapperOperation alloc] initWithRepresentation:parsedData
                                                           mappingsDictionary:mappingsDictionary];
[mapper setMappingOperationDataSource:datasource];

NSError *mappingError = nil;
BOOL isMapped = [mapper execute:&mappingError];
if (isMapped && !mappingError) {
    // data is in [mapper mappingResult]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can see how RestKit does this internally in the `RKManagedObjectResponseMapperOperation` class.

There are three stages of this operation.

The first is to parse the JSON string into NSDictionarys, NSArrays, etc. This is the easiest part.

```
id parsedData = [RKMIMETypeSerialization objectFromData:data
                                               MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON
                                                  error:error];
```

Next you need to run a mapping operation to convert this data into your NSManagedObjects. This is a bit more involved.

```
__block NSError *blockError = nil;
__block RKMappingResult *mappingResult = nil;
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
```

Remember to replace this dictionary with your own mappings. The key `[NSNull null]` maps this object from the root.

```
    NSDictionary *mappings = @{[NSNull null]: [jotOfflineRequestStatus mapping]};

    RKMapperOperation *mapper = [[RKMapperOperation alloc] initWithRepresentation:parsedData
                                                               mappingsDictionary:mappings];

    RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource *dataSource = [[RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource alloc]
                                                             initWithManagedObjectContext:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].persistentStoreManagedObjectContext
                                                             cache:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].managedObjectCache];
    dataSource.operationQueue = operationQueue;
    dataSource.parentOperation = mapper;
    mapper.mappingOperationDataSource = dataSource;

    [mapper start];
    blockError = mapper.error;
    mappingResult = mapper.mappingResult;
}];
```

You now need to run the tasks that have been put into the operationQueue we created. It is at this stage that connections to existing NSManagedObjects are made.

```
if ([operationQueue operationCount]) {
    [operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
}
```

Comment: +1! The key for my implementation was your last step, operationQueue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished(). Without that, the mapping process was returning my NSManagedObject before it has finished mapping the needed relationships.

Comment: This got things working for me. How do you get RestKit to store the object back into Core Data? I tried [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:&error]; after mappingResult = mapper.mappingResult; but that didn't help. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A more iOS 5+ oriented answer:

```
NSString* JSONString = jsonString;
NSString* MIMEType = @"application/json";
NSError* error = nil;
id<RKParser> parser = [[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] parserForMIMEType:MIMEType];
id parsedData = [parser objectFromString:JSONString error:&error];
if (parsedData == nil && error) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: JSON parsing error");
}

RKObjectMappingProvider* mappingProvider = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider;
RKObjectMapper* mapper = [RKObjectMapper mapperWithObject:parsedData mappingProvider:mappingProvider];
RKObjectMappingResult* result = [mapper performMapping];
if (result) {

    NSArray *resultArray = result.asCollection;

    MyObject *object = [resultArray lastObject];
    NSLog(@"My Object: %@", object);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Restkit 0.22, You can use this code. This returns an RKMappingResult wherein you can enumerate the objects after mapping using the property .array.

```
- (RKMappingResult *)mapJSONStringWithString:(NSString *)jsonString
{
     RKMappingResult *result = nil;

     NSError* error;
     NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     id parsedData = [RKMIMETypeSerialization objectFromData:data MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON error:&error];
     if (parsedData == nil && error) {
        NSLog(@"json mapping error");
     }

     NSDictionary *mappingsDictionary = @{@"":[CustomMappingClass getMappingForUsers]};

     ObjectClass *obj = [ObjectClass new];
     RKMapperOperation *mapper = [[RKMapperOperation alloc] initWithRepresentation:parsedData mappingsDictionary:mappingsDictionary];
     NSError *mappingError = nil;
     mapper.targetObject = obj;
     BOOL isMapped = [mapper execute:&mappingError];
     if (isMapped && !mappingError) {
         result = [mapper mappingResult];
     }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this not what you're looking for? http://restkit.org/api/0.10.0/Classes/RKJSONParserJSONKit.html

Comment: I am aware of these parser classes. They parse the string into `NSDictionary` which is the first part of the whole deserialization process. I need the functionality that takes a string and outputs the mapped objects. In other words, out of the three things that RestKit does in sequence (download response, parse the downloaded string, map objects), I need something that does the last two only.

Comment: Hey, I've got the same problem. I've got some JSON I need to map to my model (NSManagedObject). Did you find any solution for that?

Comment: @MikeBevz: I wrote my own mapper. :-) I wrote more details as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the views without any answers, it seems this facility does not exist in RestKit yet. Instead of spending more time trying to figure out how to do the mapping, I wrote my own mapper using the output of JsonKit parser and removed the dependency on RestKit (used the builtin classes for network activity). Right now my mapper is not generic (it has a few dependencies on how the objects are laid out and their names in json) but it works for the purposes of the project. I might come back later and turn it into a more generic object mapping library later on.

EDIT: This was selected answer because there was no other answer as of this answer's date (Jan 21, 2012). Since then, I stopped working on iOS and never visited this question again. Now I am selecting Ludovic's answer because of another user's comment and the upvotes for that answer.

Comment: Why is this the selected answer? Ludovic's solution works great!

Comment: @Kyle: This was selected answer because there was no other answer as of this answer's date (Jan 21, 2012). Since then, I stopped working on iOS and never visited this question again. Even though I have no means to verify the answer myself at the moment, I am selecting Ludovic's answer because of your comment.