# iOS RestKit 0.2 What is the best way to parse local Json

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I wave read many articles about parsing a json via an Http request but almost none answers the question about what is the most straight forward way to parse o local json string. I found some deferent solutions here [Deserializing local NSString of JSON into objects via RestKit (no network download)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873607/deserializing-local-nsstring-of-json-into-objects-via-restkit-no-network-downlo) some of them work some others don't. Is there any "official" RestKit support for local JSON string deserialization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately Apple provides "NSJSONSerialization" class from iOS 5.0. to serialise your data.
Step 1 : convert your local JSON string to "NSData"

```
     NSString *strLocalJSON = @"{data= "some data"}"; //just for ex. may not be valid one
     NSData *dataJSON = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Step2:

```
   id jsonobject= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataJSON options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil]; // resulting object may contain Dictionary or Array depends on your localjson
```

for further info refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON is in a file then you use a `file://` NSURL when you create your RestKit object manager. Everything else works as normal.

If the JSON is already in code, then you should save it to a file, or why are you needing to do any mapping? Anyway, you could use a combination of `NSJSONSerialization` and `RKMappingOperation`.