# How to create a database In iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, arrays, xcode

I have a very simple application, and i want to add into it a database. For all of you, to understand what i mean, it should look similar like default application "Contacts" in iPhone. It should contain list of elements (like people names in contact list), and when the user click name, the next view appear, which contain information about contact (and other buttons as well). All of data must be inside of application (not downloading from web pages).

Please help me! I am novice, and i have no clue what i should looking for, not just an array i guess... i will gratefully accept any of advice and links to examples, related to my problem.

PS. My app is not about contacts, its about diet. For example, it should look like: user click element "cheese" in list, and then  next view provide information about product (calories, protein, fat etc.)

Comment: You most likely will be better off using Core Data than SQLite. Discussion on the pros and cons here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318467/use-coredata-or-sqlite-on-iphone

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following free lessons from iTunes U. Paul Hegarty is an excellent teacher. These are dense so I had to watch a couple times, but everything you need is here:

Basic Persistence:
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/285

Core Data (Lecture):
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/287

Core Data Demo:
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/289

These pages have the pdfs, but go to iTunes and download the full lectures for an excellent overview. Also don't miss the CoreDataTableViewController available on the last linked page - handy.

Without this course I would not be an iOS developer, so I can't recommend it highly enough.

Enjoy,

Damien